# Using different methods of System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain

Tags: active-directory, powershell-2.0, directoryservices

The static method of GetCurrentDomain() works without issue but, when I try to use another method such as FindDomainController(), I receive a MethodNotFound exception error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Domain.FindDomainController` method to find all DC in the domain:

```
[System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetComputerDomain().DomainControllers
```

`[System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]` doesn't have a  `FindDomainController()` method.

or use `Domain.FindDomainController Method`

```
 [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetCurrentDomain().FindDomainController()
```

This one finds any domain controller in the domain. There is no guarantee that the same domain controller will be found by another call to this method.

Comment: [MSDN Domain Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.domain.aspx)   So looking at the domain class, FindDomainController is listed as one of the methods which was throwing me off. Basically, I have to get a domain object first and the call the FindDomainController method to get a list of domain controllers? Thanks C.B.

Comment: @JKStinn. Yes, you needa domain object! Glad to help!